# Splitting display of prop data between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a master detail React app that displays a list of todos in the main view.  I would like to modify the map loop so that each item is clickable.  When you click, it shows the remainder of the props in another component... Like so:

List component that renders out items:

```
<ul>
  {project.tasks.map((task) =>
    <li key={task.id}>
      {task.title} // need to make title clickable and then
      <Details />  // pass remainder of props to another component
    </li>
  )}
</ul>
```

Tasks has a bunch of other properties such as description, notes, end_date, etc.  When the user clicks on an item I want the remainder to show in another component that is a right sidebar which is a functional component. I am using hardcoded data at the moment in projects array that is saved in state. I am wondering if this should be a class Component with state instead of functional component...hmm.

Right Sidebar:

```
const Details = (props) => (
  <div style={{
    flex: 1,
    height: '100vh',
    overflow: 'auto',
    background: '#eee'
  }}>
  <div style={{ padding: '20px' }} {...props}/>
     {task.description}
     {task.notes}
     {task.otherStuff}
  </div>
);
```

When I do it this way....I get the error 'task not defined'  Somehow my props are not getting here.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```js
const project = {tasks: [{id: 'id1', title: 'title1', notes: 'note1', description: 'des1'}, {id: 'id2', title: 'title2', notes: 'note2', description: 'des2'}]};

const Details = ({task, ...props}) => (
  <div style={{
    flex: 1,
    overflow: 'auto',
    background: '#eee'
  }}>
  <div style={{ padding: '20px' }} {...props}/>
     <div>{task.description}</div>
     <div>{task.notes}</div>
  </div>
);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {project.tasks.map((task) =>
        <li key={task.id}>
          <a href="/">{task.title}</a>
          <Details task={task}/>
        </li>
      )}
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: i didn't use forEach(). where is forEach() in my code?

Comment: I know. It's nuts. It must be something incorrect I am doing with the spread.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the props in your `Details`component

```
<ul>
  {project.tasks.map((task) =>
    <li key={task.id}>
      {task.title} // need to make title clickable and then
      <Details task={task} />  // pass remainder of props to another component
    </li>
  )}
</ul>
```

then in Details

```
const Details = ({...props}) => ( // <---- desctructuring
  <div style={{
    flex: 1,
    height: '100vh',
    overflow: 'auto',
    background: '#eee'
  }}>
  <div style={{ padding: '20px' }} />
     {task.description}
     {task.notes}
     {task.otherStuff}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

get the rest of the props using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) :

```
<ul>
  {project.tasks.map(({id, title, ...rest}) =>
    <li key={id}>
      {title} // need to make title clickable and then
      <Details remainderOfProps={rest} />  // pass remainder of props to another component
    </li>
  )}
</ul>
```